# Binary into 2's compliment

Tags: binary, complement

if I convert the binary number 000000 into 2's compliment I will get
1's compliment (invert) = 111111
2's compliment (add +1) = here I run into a problem, does this return 000000 and the 1 gets discarded or does this return 1000000?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It discards the `1`. The condition is similar to the [Arithmetic Overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_overflow).

Strength of two's complement is that it helps us retain a binary representation when signed numbers are to be considered, because in mathematics, the value of `0` is same as that of `-0`. If we have to give up one entire bit just for sign, then, in a 4-bit word, `0000` would denote `0` and `1000` would denote `-0`, wasting one representation. The two's complement helps get rid of this. If we assume 4-bit words:

`val  -val  bits of val  two's complement bits of -val (1's complement + 1)
0    0     0000         0000 (1111+0001)
1    -1    0001         1111 (1110+0001)
2    -2    0010         1110 (1101+0001)
3    -3    0011         1101 (1100+0001)
...
7    -7    0111         1001 (1000+0001)
8    -8    (no rep)     1000 (0111+0001)`

(note that for `-8` you have one's complement of `8` in an unsigned manner, i.e.`8 = 1000` and hence its *one's complement* is `0111`).

Thus you gain a representation for `-8` by making `0` and `-0` have the same bit pattern, i.e. `0000`. Using this, for `n` bits, we can represent *all* integer values between `-2^(n-1)` to `2^(n-1)-1`.